# Is the sentence "I tried charging my phone, but in vain" correct?

Tags: grammaticality

Is the phrase "but in vain" correct to use as a dependent clause?

Comment: Perhaps consider "to no avail," instead?

Comment: I don't think there is much wrong with it. It would, however, be more usual, idiomatically, to say *I tried, but in vain, to charge my phone*.

Comment: In AmE "in vain" sounds like a very theatrical way to describe failing to charge a phone.

Comment: @RaceYouAnytime Even if your need to make a phone call was to summon a lifeboat or a rescue helicopter?

Answer (score 3):

People often use an independent clause, "I tried charing my phone, but ***my efforts*** were in vain", or "I tried charging my phone, but ***it was*** in vain", in order to be clear. However, the way you have it, with a dependent clause, is not grammatically incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

The expression "in vain" is inherently *dramatic*, and since it's ironic to have it applied to something as trivial as charging a phone, it sounds odd that you toss it off so lightly.  I would instead play up the "hopeless futility" aspect by adding something like:

> I tried to charge my phone, but *alas --it was all in vain*.

Still, there's nothing wrong with your sentence.

Comment: What if your ability to make a phone call were a matter of life and death? *I tried in vain to charge my phone* - is perfectly idiomatic.

Comment: @WS2  Then the context would supply the drama.  Either way I agree the original sentence is *idiomatic*, just less *interesting* than I would expect.